# Bootstrap carousel doesn't auto slide on mobile?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

using bootstrap carousel on my website. The user can select if he wants it to slide by time or by hand. On my computer it works fine, but on my mobile (iphone) when I choose the auto slide method it doesn't work.

Here is my carousel tag:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-touch="true" data-interval="false">
```

(all the other 200 of what to show inside it and mode choosing are not important)

Here is the method to make it auto slide:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 1000
        })
    });

</script>
```

I did to try to fix it by putting the jQuery link before the bootstrap one. But no change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Share your ```<script>```  & ```<head>```  even better would be the whole HTML page provided its not very very long

Comment: Is this snippet before the jquery call? Are you getting a `$ is not defined` error?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution for this;

1- Give a `ref` to your "next" button using `useRef` hook.

2- Use `useEffect` hook with empty array

3- In useEffect, execute a click to the button so it triggers autocyle

so;

```
const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    buttonRef.current.click();
  }, []);

...codes

<button
   className="carousel-control-prev"
   type="button"
   data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval"
   data-bs-slide="next"
   ref={buttonRef}
        >
```